# Integration over derivative of delta distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

It is well [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives) that $\delta'(x)\phi(x)=-\delta(x)\phi'(x)$ in a distributional sense, for some well behaved test function $\phi(x)$. However, what about the case:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \,\delta'(x+y+z)\phi(y)\psi(z)=~~???$$

Is this equal to zero? Or maybe it is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,(\phi'(y)\psi(z)+\phi(y)\psi'(z))$? Who knows?

Comment: Yes, it's zero, since the function that is adjacent to the delta function is independent of x.

Comment: @Paul And what if instead of $\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x+y+z)$ we had $\delta'(x+y+z)$? Would it still be zero? And if not, how would one go about parameterizing this case? In fact, let me edit the question to ask about this case instead, since it seems more non-trivial.

Comment: What does $\delta'$ mean here?  A derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @Paul This is a derivative with respect to the full delta function argument $a$, which is $a=x+y+z$.

Comment: For this case you need the co-area formula (as you would even without the derivative).

Comment: @Ian Could you please elaborate a bit on that? I am not familiar with a co-area formula.

Comment: The co-area formula says that to integrate over (say) $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is enough to integrate over the level sets $S_y$ of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (which are $(n-1)$-dimensional manifolds), and then integrate in $y$. The resulting change of variable needs a factor of $|\nabla f|$ in the denominator of the new integral. If you have a multivariable argument inside a delta function, simply take that to be your $f$; then only the level set $S_0$ will actually contribute to the integration but you will get the correct $(n-1)$-dimensional integral.

Comment: Thus for example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y) \delta(x+y) dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{g(x,z-x)}{\sqrt{2}} \delta(z) dz dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{g(x,-x)}{\sqrt{2}} dx$ Perhaps it was obvious that only $g(x,-x)$ could possibly contribute to the integration, but it was probably not obvious that there should be this $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Ian The notation seems nebulous.  One could interpret the notation to mean $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \langle g(\cdot,y),\delta_{-y} \rangle \,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(-y,y)\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y,-y)\,dy$$

Comment: @MarkViola This usage is quite standard, in part because it plays nicely with nascent delta functions (and more general approximation of distributions by integration against smooth functions).

Comment: Where does the factor of $1/\sqrt 2$ come from?  If you have a reference, I'd appreciate your sharing it herein.

Comment: As I said this is the co-area formula, it is a standard aspect of geometric measure theory. The division by the gradient is just like the usual Jacobian factor in change of variables. I don't have a particular reference for geometric measure theory though.

Comment: @Ian This is very new to me and interesting! I too would very much like to read more about it if you know of a reference. If there are more than two integrations, does it generalize like $\int dx_1dx_2...dx_n g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\delta(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)=\int dz dx_2...dx_n\frac{g(z-\sum_{i=2}^n x_i,x_2,...,x_n)}{\sqrt{n}}\delta(z)$? And how does the derivative $\delta'$ get resolved? So many things still curious about...

Comment: @Ian Wait a second! but isn't it sufficient in the example $\int dx\int dy \,g(x,y)\delta(x+y)$ to make a change of variables $x=x'-y$? Then $dx\wedge dy=dx'\wedge dy$ is still true, so we just did a trivial translation. Then $\int dx'\int dy \,g(x'-y,y)\delta(x')$ and there is no factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my example specifically: I forgot that in this case $dS(x)=\sqrt{2} dx$ so the factor is canceled. A better example: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y) \delta(x^2+y^2-1) dx dy = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2r} g(r,\theta) r dr d \theta$ (with the obvious abuse of notation about the two different $g$'s). One could also have seen this by directly changing to polar coordinates and then noting that (by the usual definition of composition involving a delta function) $\delta(r^2-1)=\frac{1}{2}(\delta(r-1)-\delta(r-1))$.

Comment: @Ian I see. So what you are saying is that as long as we can introduce a change of variables in any of the variables involved, such that e.g. $x\to x'$ where $x'=f(x,y)$ and $f$ is the function appearing in the $\delta(f(x,y))$, then get the proper Jacobian for the change of variables, we get what is needed automatically? I guess that's true at least when the change of variables is not singular. But those are probably the only cases where the coarea formula is true as well? In which case, what is the point of coarea formula if its content reduces to change of variables? Did I miss something?

Comment: The coarea formula tells you how to just factor out one variable without needing to iron out all the details of how to parametrize the level set. This can be a good thing in high dimensions where such things can get rather tedious, especially if you actually have a lot of symmetry anyway. Consider for instance the complexity of parametrizing a sphere in 15 dimensional space compared to the formula of the surface area of such a sphere.

Comment: Yet another error in my correction: the $dr$ should not be there. Egh, mistakes galore...still, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case using the co-area formula define the plane $P_c$ by $x+y+z=c$ and its surface measure by $dS_c$, then

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \delta'(x+y+z) \phi(y) \psi(z) dx dy dz & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{P_c} \delta'(c) \phi(y) \psi(z) dS_c dc \\
& = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{d}{dc} \left. \int_{P_c} \phi(y) \psi(z) dS_c \right |_{c=0} \end{align}

To finish the problem you should choose a parametrization of the plane, compute the integral with $c$ as a parameter and then differentiate. I think that since there is no other dependence on $x$ that you will actually get zero (by parametrizing the plane by $(y,z)$ taking $x=c-y-z$).